# iOS flash screen bug

Tags: ios, animation, uikit, screenshot

The screen occasionally has a flashing translucent rectangle, the point of this question is I DON'T write any animation code.The Screen appear some black blocks?Why?When I Screenshot ,it will disappear.
please see link
https://youtu.be/DnUdHAa8_SQ
https://youtu.be/W6dio0CXxlk

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Please include animation code.

Comment: the point of this question is I DON'T write any animation code

Comment: does your code have any calls to show / hide the status bar?